# "GoogleApiClient has an optional Plus.API and is not connected to Plus"

Tags: android, google-api-client, runtimeexception, google-plus-signin

I am using google login for my android app, off lately i am getting Runtime exception reports with error "***GoogleApiClient has an optional Plus.API and is not connected to Plus. Use GoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API) to guard this call.***"

Answer (score 0):

In activity result obtained from google sign in use this

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Plus.API)) {
            Person person  = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (person != null) {
                //Take the required action 
                Log.i(TAG, "Display Name: " + person.getDisplayName());
                Log.i(TAG, "Gender: " + person.getGender());
                Log.i(TAG, "About Me: " + person.getAboutMe());
                Log.i(TAG, "Birthday: " + person.getBirthday());
                Log.i(TAG, "Current Location: " + person.getCurrentLocation());
                Log.i(TAG, "Language: " + person.getLanguage());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error!");
            }
```